# Determining whether subset is vectorial subset of P

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $P_n$ a vectorial space of polynomials with a degree less or equal to $n$. Determine which of the following subsets are vectorial subspaces of $P_n$

1. $A=p(x);p(7)=0$
2. $B=p(x);p(-5)=2+p(3)$

So I know there are three factors to consider a subset as a vectorial subset:

1. To be closed under addition.
2. To be closed under scalar multiplication.
3. To have a  vector $0$

But I don't know what to change if we're talking in terms of polynomial degrees.

EDIT. Assuming nothing changes, function $A$ meets the 3rd requirement since $p(7)=0$ includes the vector of cero. I'm wondering if it meets the 2nd requirement since $p(7)=0$ times anything gives $0$ which is an element of the subset.

Comment: Nothing changes (except you have to know what the $0$ vector is in this context, and how addition and scalar multiplication of vectors i.e. functions works).

Comment: @kccu updated my question since as you mentioned the same principle of vectorial subsets is used. Now I only need to understand how to prove the next two factors.